# How can I read snort logs in NIDS mode?

Tags: snort, log-analysis

I am reading some snort logs from a firewall, I could read some with "snort -r file"

But when I had tried the newest logs I get this error:

> snort -r snort.log
>
> Running in packet dump mode
>
> ```
>    --== Initializing Snort ==--
> ```
>
> Initializing Output Plugins!
> pcap DAQ configured to read-file.
>
> ERROR: Can't initialize DAQ pcap (-1) - unknown file format
>
> Fatal Error, Quitting..

Probably the snort is running in NIDS mode, I don't know, I have barnyard into this system if help.
Is there any material to help me understand and troubleshoot this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: When I Google your error, it appears to be a local snort install issue. Has your snort environment changed? Can you open the previous router logs without an error?

Comment: I'm not sure if the environment has changed, in true I'm doing an forensic investigation. The firewall is server in Linux Red Hat, others logs I can read normally. I had tried open this logs with wireshark, but I failed too.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that problem is about the format of snort output, the logs that I could read is alert logging, the logs that I can't read area unified2.

> Unified2 can work in one of three modes, packet logging, alert logging, or true unified logging. Packet logging includes a capture of the entire packet and is specified with log_unified2. Likewise, alert logging will only log events and is specified with alert unified2. To include both logging styles in a single, unified file, simply specify unified2.

https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-unified2

Thx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the option `-r` is related to analyze *.pcap* files. That's why you came across this error output:

```
ERROR: Can't initialize DAQ pcap (-1) - unknown file format
```

---

To be able to capture the Snort logs, you need to specify whether it will go to syslog or it will be stored in some desired file. In both options will need a monitor to read the latest logs generated (e.g.: the `tail(1)` can be your friend at that time.)

According to the `snort(8)` manpage:

`-l`: set the output log. By default is set to `/var/snort/log`;

`-i`: set the specific interface to sniff packets;

`-s`: send log to syslog;

`-c`: set the config file that contain the rules;

---

#### Example of use:

**Capture logs from `eth0`:**

```
./snort -i eth0 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l ./snort-eth0.log
```

Use `tail -f ./snort-eth0.log` on another console to look at the logs in real time. If you want to send to the syslog, just add the `-s` at the end of the snort command line.

**Capture logs from snort running in Daemon mode:**

First, you need to know where snort is spitting the logs. To do this, check what was specified in the flag `-l`. If it is not specified, remember that the default path is `/var/snort/log`.

```
ps -p $(pidof /opt/snort3/bin/snort) -f
...
tail -f /var/snort/log
```